# Error: change the path of the translation files using EasyLocalization Flutter

Tags: flutter

I´m new using flutter and I'm trying to implement EasyLocalization in my project, I have two project, one for the json files and other to the app, but I don't know how I can set the path to recognize the files hosted in the project of the traslations. Below my code:

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jarvis_ui/jarvis_ui.dart';

import './src/ui/view/view.dart';
import 'idle.dart';
import 'src/ui/ui.dart';
import 'src/ui/view/error/error.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  String defaultRoute = window.defaultRouteName;
  Uri _uri = Uri.parse(defaultRoute);
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    <DeviceOrientation>[
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ],
  );
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: <Locale>[
        Locale('es', 'CL'),
        Locale('es', 'CO'),
        Locale('es', 'PE'),
      ],
      fallbackLocale: Locale('es', 'CL'),
      path: 'packages/ui_shared/assets/languages',
      assetLoader: RootBundleAssetLoader(),
      child: ProviderScope(
        observers: <ProviderObserver>[
          // Logger(),
        ],
        child: MyApp(params: _uri.queryParameters),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends HookWidget {
  const MyApp({required this.params});
  final Map<String, dynamic> params;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => IdleApp(params: params);
}
```

In `import 'package:jarvis_ui/jarvis_ui.dart';` is hosted the json files for the traslations. Then, I think that the correct way to assign the path was:  `path: 'packages/ui_shared/assets/languages',` but I was wrong. The error is here:

[image]

In the pubspec.yaml of project that I have the json files stored, I have this:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/languages/
```

Thank you so much if you can help me with this.